# Is it possible to avoid ADK uses in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, sdk, stripe-payments, cloudinary

I need to implement few features, however, they do not seem to be possible, and I don't have a lot of implementation time.

I have a solution PCL *(.NET 4.5, Profile=111)* and for some reasons (that I don't understand from hours now), I can't install the following packages :

- Stripe (The only one that can be installed is Stripe.net, but I can only install it on Android and iOS, not on the PCL part..)
- Cloudinary (I tried all of them and... It's not compatible with `.NET 4.5, Profile=111`)

Do you have any idea or any work around to make it work? I need Stripe for payments and Cloudinary for images hosting. It's already what the company is using so, I have to adapt.

I was thinking about don't use any sdk and just do everything by myself, is it allowed/possible?

Answer (score 0):

Both of that packages have .Net Standard targets so i would prefer to use new *.csproj vs2017 format with library targeting .Net Standard. That is not an PCL that targets .Net Standard, this is not an PCL at all. 
.Net Standard library with new csproj format have some advantages like:

- Ability to install old nuget packages that targeting platforms as well as new packages that targeting .Net Standard(as opposite to PCL that can install only ald packages)
- Ability to edit csproj file on the fly without unloading project
- Simplified csproj file
- Cleaner look of dependencies
- Smoother work (fewer bugs problems)
- Some other stuff Im not aware of

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) is full list of changes.

For that you need to create new project from template .Net Standard->Class Library(.Net Standard). Than install all nuget packages there and link that project from your platform projects. Old PCL can be deleted. [Here](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) is some guide to migrate.
 Note: to install old nuget packages that targets .Net Portable you need to add in your csproj file similar lines:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81</PackageTargetFallback>
    <PackageTargetFallback>net461</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`PackageTargetFallback` attribute for every target framework you library needs. That will allow old packages to pass target checks.

Comment: I'm a but lost, I read and tried but it's not clear to me.. I need to create a .NET solution and add each sub platform? Is that what they say?

Comment: in you crossplatform solution you need to add projects for every platform (android, ios etc) and target some environment for that platform(like mono, monotouch etc). And you could add some project with crossplatform code. That project will be shared library, portable class library or .Net Standard library. The whole answer is about crossplatform project with .Net Standard library.